# SOLR - Index analyzing - FieldNorm

Tags: java, solr, wcs

So i am using LUKE to check a SOLR index used by IBM WCS7. I found some fields having the FieldNorm byte which means they must have been boosted when indexed. 
my question is, what could be the thing boosting these fields while indexing? usually it should be an update request but i am sending none and still find these field boosted. any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking directly on solr or are you checking the result of a search query fired from WCS?
"fieldNorm is the combination of length of the field with index and query 
time boosts"

The boost can be either index time boosts or query time boosts. Also It is not clear from the question whether the fields you are looking at are OOB fields or a custom fields you have added to SOLR.

If it is OOB, you must be looking at pre-processing/schema/wc-data-config xmls to see if there are any boosts added. Also check the DataImportHandler class that you use to index the docs in SOLR.

It is also possible to that we can give special commands to DIH  for boosting. For example : $docBoost, The below link explains
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands